# Error Handling in Workbook Index For Loop

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am trying to sum indexed values from across several worksheets, and I have a method that works. The issue is error handling. It is common that the `Match` function returns an error when it cannot find a match.

```
    For i = 3 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
    
        Debug.Print "Work Plz " & ws.Name
        'Test On Error Resume Next, works for the most part, fails at a few sheets in
        
        On Error Resume Next
            
        Cat = WorksheetFunction.Match(Crit1, ws.Range("B4:B34"), 0)
        Dat = WorksheetFunction.Match(Crit2, ws.Range("C2:N2"), 0)
        Val = WorksheetFunction.Index(ws.Range("C4:N34"), Cat, Dat)
        
        Indx = Indx + Val
    
        Debug.Print "The Match and Index " & Cat & ", " & Dat & ", " & Indx
        
    Next i
```

I tried using `On Error Resume Next`, which works to fully run the script, but an issue I am having is that at some point it decided that it didn't need to Match the `Crit1` variable. The error should occur `Sheet5` to `Sheet8`

These are expected results:

```
2024
Work Plz Sheet3
The Match and Index 14, 3, 0
Work Plz Sheet4
The Match and Index 14, 3, 0
Work Plz Sheet5
The Match and Index 14, 3, 0
Work Plz Sheet6
The Match and Index 14, 3, 0
Work Plz Sheet7
The Match and Index 14, 3, 0
Work Plz Sheet8
The Match and Index 14, 3, 0
```

And these are the results I get

```
2024
Work Plz Sheet3
The Match and Index 14, 3, 0
Work Plz Sheet4
The Match and Index 14, 3, 0
Work Plz Sheet5
The Match and Index 14, 3, 0
Work Plz Sheet6
The Match and Index 14, 3, 95.74
Work Plz Sheet7
The Match and Index 14, 3, 95.74
Work Plz Sheet8
The Match and Index 14, 3, 95.74
```

Comment: If an error occurs, the assignment statement is not executed and the variable retains its current value.

Comment: Consider using `Application.Match` and `IsError`, instead of `WorksheetFunction.Match`.

Comment: Please also consider using a different variable than `Val`. That shadows the [`Val`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) function.

Comment: @bigben I made the changes you recommended, and created an `If Not IsError(Cat)` and it seems to have set everything to zero regardless

Comment: @bigben Disregard my statement, I got it to work, I found a discrepancy in my code, I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Cat and Dat to your Debug.Print and I'll bet the answer will become obvious.

I've found that a lot of my error handling problems are resolved by isolating what I'm trying to error-handle as its own procedure. For example, I'm guessing what you're having issues with would be resolved by splitting part of your code to its own function...

```vb
Function GetVal(i, Crit1, Crit2) As Double
  On Error Goto ErrorSub

  Dim Cat As Integer
  Dim Dat As Integer
  Dim ws as Worksheet

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
            
  Cat = WorksheetFunction.Match(Crit1, ws.Range("B4:B34"), 0)
  Dat = WorksheetFunction.Match(Crit2, ws.Range("C2:N2"), 0)
  GetVal = WorksheetFunction.Index(ws.Range("C4:N34"), Cat, Dat)
ExitSub:
  Exit Function
ErrorSub:
  Resume ExitSub
End Function
```

Then you can call it, and if there are any bugs outside GetVal, those errors can be unhandled or handled differently.

```
    For i = 3 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Val = GetVal(i, Crit1, Crit2)
        Indx = Indx + Val
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution was developed with the help of @BigBen who commented above

```
Function CustIndex(Crit1 As Variant, Crit2 As Variant) As Double

Dim IndVal As Double
Dim Cat As Long
Dim Dat As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

For i = 3 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
    
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Crit1, ws.Range("B4:B34"), 0)) Then
        Cat = Application.Match(Crit1, ws.Range("B4:B34"), 0)
        Dat = Application.Match(Crit2, ws.Range("C2:N2"), 0)
        IndVal = WorksheetFunction.Index(ws.Range("C4:N34"), Cat, Dat)
    Else
        IndVal = 0
    End If
    
    CustIndex = CustIndex + IndVal
    
Next i
End Function
```